# Recently opened files on Finder's sidebar in OSX

Tags: macos, finder, sidebar

OSX Finder (seemingly randomly) adds documents I open to the sidebar under "FAVORTIES" section. How can I stop that?

I use OSX 10.8.5 on a Retina MacBook Pro 15.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually figured this out. It turns out the hotkey for adding something to sidebar is Cmd+T which is the same as opening a tab in a browser. I was basically adding the items to the sidebars when tabbing between Finder and Chrome. Since it happened about once a week it seemed like Finder is magically adding random items to the sidebar.